# Do I really need to define reactive svelte variables twice?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to use svelte's reactive variables. However, it seems I need to define my function twice. Is there a way to get rid of one of the two very similar lines?

```
let reactive_var = my_function( editable_var, 32 );
$: reactive_var = my_function( editable_var, 32 );

let another_var = reactive_var * 4;
```

Removing the first line messes up the definition of `another_var`.

Answer (score 0):

If `another_var` is reactive as well (which it should be), then it needs a reactive declaration as well. Slightly modified example from the [Svelte tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations) :

```html
<script>
    let count = 0;
    $: doubled = count * 2;
    $: quad = doubled * 2;

    function handleClick() {
        count += 1;
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Clicked {count} {count === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>

<p>{count} doubled is {doubled}</p>
<p>{count} multiplied by 4 is {quad}</p>
```

Comment: I isn't reactive, It's used only once, to initialise a component: `<MyComponent bind:my_param={another_var}/>`. Do you know of any solution for that situation?

Comment: You could use an initial value and assign it to your reactive variable and to your other variable, which is pretty much what you did with a bit less of repetition. See my edit

Comment: Wouldn't that be different from my code in that `reactive_var` would not react to changes in `editable_var` ?

Comment: Ah yes my bad, indeed. Let me remove this silly suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the double declaration of `reactive_var` you could set `another_var` (the non reactive one based on the reactive) inside `onMount()` >> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3af2da726260420fbf6688e09b017e13?version=3.46.4)

```
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'

    export let editable_var

    $: reactive_var = my_function( editable_var, 32 );
    let non_reactive_var
    
    onMount(() => {
        non_reactive_var = reactive_var * 4;
    })
```

Or with the function twice, but still one line less..

```
    let non_reactive_var = my_function( editable_var, 32 ) * 4;

    $: reactive_var = my_function( editable_var, 32 );
```